# Writing to quota folder as owner of folder instead of anyother user

Tags: linux, debian, chown, quota

I have a Debian Jessie machine. A hard disk mounted on its `/home` folder.

My `/etc/fstab` looks like

```
/dev/vda1 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0  1                            
/dev/vdb swap swap defaults 0 0
/dev/vdc1 /home ext4 defaults,usrquota 0 2
```

I have a quota folder at `/home` namely `plusone` with `softlimit 2GB` and
`hardlimit 3GB`. A user `plusone` has been added.

The commands for creating the quota folder and user

```
mkdir /home/plusone
chmod 777 -R /home/plusone
useradd -d /home/plusone plusone -p plusone
chown -R plusone:plusone /home/plusone
setquota -u plusone 2000000 3000000 0 0 /home/
```

My question is,

Whenever any file written to `plusone` folder by **any user**, **any way** the owner must be
 `plusone` by default. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Linux does not support this on the kernel level, see https://superuser.com/questions/471844/why-is-setuid-ignored-on-directories for a little more details. Basically, giving away files is generally considered too dangerous and not terribly useful; FreeBSD supports this via [setuid directories](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?chmod), though.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Can I achieve the same by samba share?

Comment: No idea, sorry.